# Use icons inside SVG

Tags: html, dom, svg, icons

I have a PNG image, which I use in my HTML as background-image for `<i>` elements.
I need to use this icon inside the SVG. Putting `<i>` inside of `<foreignObject>` renders the icon, but causes lots of other problems.

Is there any way to get the icon effect inside SVG without using HTML tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SVG has an `<image>` tag very much like the one in HTML:

```
<image xlink:href="firefox.jpg" x="0" y="0" height="50px" width="50px"></image>
```

- [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/SVG/Element/image)

Comment: Thank you!
If I have lots of icons in the same png file, can I set something like `background-position` to 'zoom' the image?

Comment: Sounds like you should be asking another question

Comment: @eagor It is possible, but you should open another question for this as Robert said.

Comment: here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16983442/how-to-specify-the-portion-of-the-image-to-be-rendered-inside-svgimage-tag